# How to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find common fields between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if I need to join TableA & TableB - how can I use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database to find the common field between them?

Answer (score 6):

Here is one method:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name in ('A', 'B')
group by column_name
having count(*) = 2;
```

If necessary, you should also include `table_schema` to identify the tables.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "including table_schema"?

Comment: Multiple tables in the same database could have the same name, distinguished only by the schema they are in.

Comment: your query works but it only shows the column names shared by the 2 tables I want to join. Say, I want to join ORDR & OPOR. I'll write a query that looks like this -> select ordr.doctotal, opor.docnum from ordr join opor on ordr.primarykey = opor.foreignkey. If I already know what that the primary key of ORDR is DocEntry, how do I find the matching OPOR's foreign key to link the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get common fields in two table:

```
SELECT  C.name
FROM    SYS.OBJECTS O
JOIN    SYS.COLUMNS C
ON      O.object_id = C.object_id
WHERE   O.name IN
(
'TABLE-A', 'TABLE-B'
)
group by C.name
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to get common column in two table:

```
SELECT  A.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B ON A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE A.TABLE_NAME 'Table_1' 
AND B.TABLE_NAME = 'Table_2'
```